# Split string and Pivot Result - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a table called `XMLData` that looks like this:

| Tag | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| tag1 | Cantidad=222¬ClaveProdServ=1 |
| tag1 | Cantidad=333¬ClaveProdServ=2 |

The column `Tag` has many repeated values, what is different is the column `Attribute` that has a string of attributes separated by "¬". I want to separate the list of attributes and then pivot the table so the tags are the column names.

The result I want is like this:

| tag1 | tag1 |
| --- | --- |
| Cantidad=222 | Cantidad=333 |
| ClaveProdServ=1 | ClaveProdServ=2 |

I have a custom made function that splits the string since SQL server 2012 doesn't have a premade function that does this. The function I have receives a
string as a parameter and the delimiter like so:

```
select *
from [dbo].[Split]('lol1,lol2,lol3,lol4',',')
```

this function will return this:

| item |
| --- |
| lol1 |
| lol2 |
| lol3 |

I can't find a way to pass the  values of the column `Attribute` as parameter of this function, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Split(A.Attribute,'¬'),XMLData A
```

And then put the values of the column `Tag` as the the column names for each set of Attributes

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. And why oh why are you storing delimited values like this. You have delimited your data so badly that you actually have an entire table inside a single tuple. This doesn't just violate 1NF it laughs in the face of normalization. What you really need is to fix your data and then the retrieval becomes trivial. But if you absolutely can't fix the data you need to provide us with some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: im loading a lot of XML files from various folders in my sistem to a database, im also extrating all the data they contain (node names, values and attributes), i already normalized the database but i dont want to put the attribute list to a new table since i already have 4 tables (Folders, Files, nodes data, file namespaces), each XML have a lot of attributes in each node so the table of attributes would be quite large and also have a lot of repeated values, im doing this query just for visualization of the information in a more organized manner in case it is needed.

Comment: OK. You have explained why you don't want to normalize the data. But you didn't do anything about providing some details that explain what you really want. See the link in my previous comments and give us something to work with.

Comment: You should have a really good reason for this... Why not keep the XMLs just *as is*?

Comment: Thanks for the replys, im working in a program to manage a lot of XMLs for Electronic billing that are scattered in many different locations, the original idea was to extract some important data of the XML and its location to be able to identify it and locate it because the file names dont have any usefull information. If anyone needed more detail about a XML they could locate it easily and look for the info in the file itself.

Comment: But for some reason I was asked to store the attributes of the nodes in case they where needed, since they will probably never be used i was told to dont create a new table and store them in a single string by separating them using "¬" and store them in the same table where I stored the important info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My magic crystal ball tells me, that you have - why ever - decided to do it this way and any comments about *don't store CSV data* are just annoying to you.

How ever...

If this is just a syntax issue, try it like this:

```
SELECT t.Tag
      ,t.Attribute
      ,splitted.item
FROM YourTable AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(t.Attribute,'¬') AS splitted
```